# Best way to silently bind window resize event to jQuery plugin without keeping a reference to the targeted element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for best-practice advice.

I'm writing a small jQuery plugin to manage horizontal scroll on elements.

I need all the dom elements targeted by that plugin to update on window resize.

Fact is, my website is a full ajax 'app' so when I remove DOM elements, I need them gone so memory doesn't leak.

But I can't find a way to bind the resize event without keeping a reference to the DOM node.

EDIT :

Actually I need the resize handler to get the plugin-targeted elements at 'call' time, coz I don't want to keep any reference to those elements in memory, because **I might call .html('') on a parent of theirs**...

I did not paste all my code, just an empty shell. I already have a destroy method that unbinds handlers. But I'm generating, removing and appending html nodes dynamically and I the the elements targeted by the plugin to remove silently.

Kevin B stated I could override jQuery `.remove` method to deal with the handlers, but would have to load jQuery UI for it to work. I don't want that either..

Here is what I tried (attempts commented):

```
(function($) {
    // SOLUTION 2 (see below too)
    // Not good either coz elements are not removed until resize is triggered
    /*
    var hScrolls = $([]);
    $(window).bind('resize.hScroll',function(){
        if(!hScrolls.length) return;
        hScrolls.each(function(){
            if($(this).data('hScroll')) $(this).hScroll('updateDimensions');
            else hScrolls = hScrolls.not($(this));
        });
    });
    */
    // END SOLUTION 2

    // SOLUTION 3 (not implemented but I think I'm on the right path)
    $(window).bind('resize.hScroll',function(){
        // need to get hScroll'ed elements via selector...
        $('[data-hScroll]').hScroll('updateDimensions');
        // I don't know how....
    });
    // END SOLUTION 3
    var methods = {
        init : function(options) {
            var settings = $.extend( {
                defaults: true
            }, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('hScroll');
                if (!data) {
                    $this.data('hScroll', {
                        target: $this
                    });
                    // SOLUTION 1
                    // This is not good: it keeps a reference to $this when I remove it...
                    /*
                    $(window).bind('resize.hScroll', function(){
                        $this.hScroll('updateDimensions');
                    });
                    */
                    // END SOLUTION 1
                    $this.hScroll('updateDimensions');

                    // SOLUTION 2 (see above too)

                    hScrolls = hScrolls.add(this);

                }
            });
        },
        updateDimensions: function(){
            var hScroll = this.data('hScroll');
            // do stuff with hScroll.target
        }
    }

    $.fn.hScroll = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.hScroll');
        }
    };
})(jQuery);​
```

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: If you were using the jQuery UI Widget system you could use the destroy method, however if that isn't the case, you could extend the `.remove` method to have it also clean-up what your plugin does. You would then need to ensure that the other jQuery html methods that remove or replace elements also use `.remove` before removing the elements..

Comment: I'm not removing specific elements but entire pages, containing these elements so I won't call the .remove method on the element.

Comment: You aren't, but jQuery does when using jQuery ui, it's part of cleaning up the jQuery UI plugins automatically when they or their parents are removed.

Comment: even if I call .html('') on the parent?

Comment: yes, iirc. The only downside (which is a pretty big one) is you have to include the jQuery UI core and widget factory. You would also have to use the widget factory to some extent.

Comment: ... don't wanna do that... editing question

Comment: It won't however do the cleanup if you do `parent.innerHTML = ""` because jQuery can't intercept that.

Comment: Essentially what you are wanting though is to automatically run your destroy method when the plugin's element is "destroyed" right?

Comment: See my edited answer. It doesn't store elements at all but only the selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery calls `cleanData` any time you do something that removes or replaces elements (yes, even if you use `parent.html("")` ). You can take advantage of that by extending it and having it trigger an event on the target elements.

```
// This is taken from https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js 10/17/2012
if (!$.widget) { // prevent duplicating if jQuery ui widget is already included
    var _cleanData = $.cleanData;
    $.cleanData = function( elems ) {
        for ( var i = 0, elem; (elem = elems[i]) != null; i++ ) {
            try {
                $( elem ).triggerHandler( "remove" );
                // http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8235
            } catch( e ) {}
        }
        _cleanData( elems );
    };
}
```

Now you can bind to the remove event when setting up your plugin and have it run your destroy method.

```
$(elem).bind("remove",methods.destroy)
```

Comment: That is cool. I'm not sure I'll use it (a special class might be lighter), but that's the answer I was looking for. Thanks a ton!

Comment: No problem, I'm sorry I had so much trouble explaining exactly what I meant to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a class name and forward the resize event:

```
$.fn.hScroll = function(method) {
    this
      .addClass('hScroll')
      .data('method', arguments)
};

var methods['alert_text'] = function(config){
  alert( config + " " + $(this).text() );
}

$(window).bind('resize.hScroll',function(){
  $(".hScroll").each(function(){
     var method_config = $(this).data('method');
     var method = method_config.shift();
     // Forward the resize event with all resize event arguments:
     methods[method].apply(this, method_config);
   })
})

// Register a resize event for all a.test elements:
$("a.test").hScroll('alert_text', "hey");
// Would alert "hey you" for <a class="test">you</a> on every resize
```

---

Update

If you change the dom and want to keep the selector you might try this one:

```
var elements = [];
 $.fn.hScroll = function(method) {
     elements.push({'selector' : this.selector, 'arguments' : arguments });
 };

var methods['alert_text'] = function(config){
  alert( config + " " + $(this).text() );
}

$(window).bind('resize.hScroll',function(){
  $.each(elements,function(i, element){
    $(element.selector).each(function(){
       var method_config = element.arguments;
       var method = method_config.shift();
       // Forward the resize event with all resize event arguments:
       methods[method].apply(this, method_config);
     })
   })
})

// Register a resize event for all a.test elements:
$("a.test").hScroll('alert_text', "hey");
$(document.body).html("<a class='test'>you</a>");
// Would alert "hey you" for every window resize
```

Comment: Thx, I guess the custom class is a solution. I'd rather check the existence of the plugin implementation though. Also why not call the method directly instead of forwarding the event?

Comment: Because all elements might have different methods or different method configurations

Answer (score 0):

You should have the scroll event bound in the extension.  Also, you will want to add a "destroy" method to your extension as well.  Before you remove the element from the DOM, you will want to call this method.  Inside the detroy method is where you will want to unbind the resize event.

One important thing in making this work is that you have a reference to each handler method that is bound to the resize event.  Alternatively, you can unbind All resize events upon the removal on an element and then rebind the scroll event to the remaining elements that require it.

Comment: I have a destroy method that unbinds handlers but didn't paste it for clarity. I don't want to call a method to unbind events. That's the problem.

Comment: Then just unbind the single event that effects the removed element.  To do this you will need to keep track of each event handler for each element that is bound to the resize event

Comment: Actually I need the resize handler to get the plugin-targeted elements at 'call' time, coz I don't want to keep any reference to those elements in memory, because I might call .html('') on a parent of theirs...